# Mockito mock method input value passed as reference with given output value

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Given the following method:

```
public void method(Long a, Long b, Set<Long> out) {
    out.add(42L);
}
```

I would like to mock the out parameter that is modified upon running:

```
Set<Long> x = new HashSet<>();
x.add(1L);

Mockito.doNothing().when(service).method(anyLong(), anyLong(), any());
// How to mock the last parameter with x?
```

**Question:**

How can achieve that upon serivce run, the `Set<Long> out` parameter is mocked with a predefined value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an `Answer` is what you need:

```
Mockito.doAnswer(i -> {
    Set<Long> out = i.getArgument(2);
    out.add(42L);
    return out;
}).when(service)).method(anyLong(), anyLong(), any());
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using something based on your original answer, I edited it a slightly.

Comment: Thanks, I've approved it.

Answer (score 0):

Has the `Set<Long> out` attribute a getter? If that's the case, you can do something like:

```
when(service.getOut()).thenReturn(42L);
```